# Get Position of text inside a HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect the position of text inside a HTML element (assume, `<div>` tag) (top, left, bottom and right coordinates) on the screen. I have tried offsetLeft, and offsetWidth. But, it doesn't help. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, not sure where you got lost but you can determine coordinates using the following:

```
Top:     node.offsetTop
Left:    node.offsetLeft
Bottom:  (node.offsetTop + node.offsetHeight)
Right:   (node.offsetLeft + node.offsetWidth)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p56xgpmb/

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your reply. But, what I understand is that, these are coordinates for the `<div>` element. Text coordinates, width & height may vary. Right? How to find those?

Comment: These are the coordinates for the `p` tag, not the `div`. Text nodes do not have the same methods as element nodes so you cannot use the `offset` methods. Text Nodes cannot be targeted with CSS though, so you can safely assume the parent element's position is representative of the text node's position.

Comment: Ok. Still if you try on the link you gave to me on jsfiddle. Even deleting some text or increasing the text, the Right coordinate doesn't change

Comment: You can adjust the css of the containing element to not be full-width as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript. Then the coordinates will be accurate to the text width/height.

Comment: If the parent has other inline child nodes there will be multiple textNode which could be anywhere.